# Change Version Number SED.exe

Tags: .net, batch-file, sed

I'm using following script to replace the build number in `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")] -> [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.Build_Number")]
```

But I want to do this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")]->[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("major.minor.build_number.revision")]
```

Please let me know if anyone has worked with `SED` I'm using it for the first time so have less information about the expression terms.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SRC=%1

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :error
IF "%BUILD_NUMBER%"=="" GOTO :notset
IF NOT EXIST "%SRC%" GOTO :notfound

SED -i "s^\(Assembly\(Informational\|File\)Version(\d34[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]+\.\)\+^\1%BUILD_NUMBER%^" "%SRC%"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :failed

GOTO :eof

:notset
echo {0e}WARNING: BUILD_NUMBER environment variable not set, performing no action{#}{\n}
EXIT /b 0

:failed
echo {0c}ERROR  : Failed to process command{#}{\n}
EXIT /b 1

:notfound
echo {0c}ERROR  : Source '%1' not found{#}{\n}
EXIT /b 1

:error
echo {0c}ERROR  : Source not specified{#}{\n}
EXIT /b 1
```

Comment: The basic syntax for `sed` substitution is `s/` *old-pattern* `/` *new-value* `/` *flags* *filename*

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `bash`?  There is no `bash` in your post.

Comment: removed the tag